# Multy If Not Statment VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, boolean

```
If x = y And Not (z(0) = w(0) And z(1) = w(1) And z(2) = w(2)) then .....
```

I want to test if x = y and z(0) is not equal to w(0) and z(1) is not equal to w(0) and z(2) is not equal to w(2). Basicly ***if x=y and any of the rest is not equal to the other it should do the code in the if-statement***

Will one ***And Not (....)*** work ?

Let me know if you have alternative solutions or if this will work thanks for the help

Comment: I want to make it work like java If(!(Boolean)){.....}

Comment: It works the same as in Java. However, you should probably replace `And` with `AndAlso` (and `Or` with `OrElse`). Essentially, `And` and `Or` have no place, ever, in a boolean/`if` condition, their use is for bit operations. Look at the documentation for details on the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you say you want. It is checking if x = y and **any** of the other terms are unequal. Think about it, your if statement is asking if two things are true, the first is that x = y and the second is that the expression in parentheses is not true (and the expression in parentheses will not be true if and of the z and w terms are unequal).

If you want to check that **all** the other terms are unequal, you need

```
If x = y And z(0) <> w(0) And z(1) <> w(1) And z(2) <> w(2) then ...
```